# Run PHP-FPM as other user

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have been using a setup that I created for several years on various machines and I am now trying to run it on a Debian 12 server. The setup is similar to a forge and can be found on this URL https://serversforhackers.com/c/lemp-forge-setup. Everything used to work perfectly fine, but I am now experiencing issues on a new machine.

If I keep the PHP user as www-data and the project in `var/www`, there is no problem. However, when I move it to the home directory `/home/forge/hutzlibu`, I see an error log entry in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` that reads:

```
"/home/forge/hutzlibu/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: , server: _, request: "GET /.
```

I have tried changing the listen.owner and listen.group for the PHP config to forge, but it didn't work. I have found someone else who is experiencing similar issues on this URL https://stackoverflow.com/a/58902001/1518174.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Matz

Edit:
Some output from questions in the comments

`namei -l /home/forge/hutzlibu/public/` gaves me

```
f: /home/forge/hutzlibu/public/
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  home
drwx-----x forge forge forge
drwxr-xr-x forge forge hutzlibu
drwxr-xr-x forge forge public
```

Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/forge/hutzlibu/public;

    server_name _;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Only changed in PHP-FPM config file `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
user = forge
group = forge

# also tried with
# listen.owner = forge
# listen.group = forge
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx 403 Forbidden Error hosting in User Home Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/416787/nginx-403-forbidden-error-hosting-in-user-home-directory)

Comment: Hey, thank. Still the same issue.

Comment: The answer linked above is not very good advice on how to manage permissions,

Comment: You've not told us what the permissions are or if there is MAC configured (or how).

Comment: @symcbean which permission? It's all default. I already tried 755 for the forge home folder without any luck. I did this so many times before, no idea why it's not working for now.

Comment: Please edit the output of `namei -l /home/forge/hutzlibu/public/index.php` into your question. The nginx configuration could also be relevant, as well as the php-fpm configuration and the php-fpm systemd unit.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
listen.owner = www-data
user = forge
group = forge
```

for php-fpm.
And confirm that in nginx.conf you have `user www-data;`

And I'd also added read permissions for everyone to /home/forge. It might (or might not) help.

Comment: Thanks. I already had that configuration.

Comment: So, could you show exact error with such settings? Just wondering if it's showing the same (as IMO it shouldn't)

Comment: You can see all necessary info in the post.